# Azure AD B@C multi-tenant azure authentication issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am setting up b2c multi-tenant authentication for my app, I am flowing this steps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=applications

I am stuck with 2 problems

1. Signin with local accounts not working, Signup works fine
2. My app is a React SPA, after azure account (not local) login flow completes, I am getting 'X-Frame-Option' deny error

Comment: 1. Have you tried to login to application once you sign up to the application. please do refer the [starter pack] (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts)

2.  Regarding 'X-Frame-Option' deny error please let us know which  login service you are using an when are you getting this issue particularly

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity Yes, login after sign up is not working, Issue is with local accounts and external azure users

Comment: The issue may be with the Creation of **IdentityExperienceFramework** and **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** apps. Please recheck the registration process [document] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#register-identity-experience-framework-applications)

Comment: In my experience, Raghavendra should be right. Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve first issue by recreating IEF apps (IdentityExperienceFramework and ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework apps) with this tool b2ciefsetup.azurewebsites.net

Still facing the msal js - iframe issue
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1161